# AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I am mapping my classes with the tables of my database, but when running a test, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.modulos.pvs.acceso.datos.entity.Provincia from com.modulos.pvs.acceso.datos.entity.Ciudad has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1550)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1389)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1345)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 40 more
```

these are my classes:

```
//    PROVINCIA TABLE
    @Entity
    @Table(name="provincia")
    @NamedQuery(name = "Provincia.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Provincia p")
    public class Provincia implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EmbeddedId
        private ProvinciaPK id;

        private String nombreProvincia;

        // bi-directional many-to-one association to Region
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "codRegion")
        private Region region;

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to Ciudad
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="provincia", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Ciudad> ciudad;

    //GETTER AND SETTER

//TABLE CIUDAD
/**
 * The persistent class for the city database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="ciudad")
@NamedQuery(name = "Ciudad.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Ciudad c")
public class Ciudad implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private CiudadPK id;

    private String nombreCiudad;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Provincia
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codProvincia", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Provincia provincia;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Direcciones
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ciudad", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Direcciones> direcciones;

//  GETTER AND SETTER
```

both have primary keys are embedded into classes.

```
//PROVINCIA PK
/**
 * The primary key class for the provincia database table.
 * 
 */
@Embeddable
public class ProvinciaPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String codProvincia;

    private String codRegion;

    public ProvinciaPK() {
    }
    /getter and setter

//ciudad pk
/**
 * The primary key class for the region database table.
 * 
 */
@Embeddable
public class CiudadPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String codCiudad;

    private String codProvincia;

    public CiudadPK() {
    }
//GETTER AND SETTER
```

and this is my relational model database

[image]

anyone have any idea? of that does not work?

EDIT 30/11/2014 - RETURN TO LIST EMPTY ASSOCIATION
this is my JUnit test

```
Region region = new Region();
            region.setId(new RegionPK("RM","CHL"));

            region.setProvincias(regionDAO.getProvinciaRegion(region));

            System.out.println(region.getProvincias());
```

This is the method that returns me the association of provincias

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public List<Provincia> getProvinciaRegion(Region region) {
    region = getRegionById(region);
    Hibernate.initialize(region.getProvincias());
    return region.getProvincias();
}
```

and this I have in the database

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Your class `CiudadPK` has two columns in it.  You're only using `@JoinColumn` which is limited to a single column.  You need to use `@JoinColumns` and list out both columns in the FK, e.g.

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to Provincia
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "codProvincia", insertable = false, updatable = false),
  @JoinColumn(name = "codRegion", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private Provincia provincia;
```

You'll likely have the other issue w/ `Ciudad` as well, please follow the pattern here to correct that one.

Comment: Thanks, it worked !, but I have a doubt, because I requires two foreign keys if my table has only one? It is something I have not understood

Comment: You're getting a composite primary key because you're using an `@EmbeddedId` in your code.  Was this not your intention?

Comment: if it was, had confused me, but you enlighten me and I understood.
otherwise, because now I try to return the list REGION asociasones in class, but I returns an empty list, you know why is that?.
I edited the post with information about this

Comment: I have no idea what `Hibernate.initialize` is, is that custom code of yours?  Best bet is to start a new question explaining what you're trying to do.  Also compare to your domain model - you're missing codCiudad

Comment: It works, but when i save a new entity Ciudad, i got a "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" for Provincia", why?

Comment: Thanks! You saved me time!

Comment: I got here because of this issue but I already used JoinColumns , though it is a OneToOne. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I am using inverseJoinColumn and don't work what is the problem

Answer (score 10):

As of Java 8 (introducing [@Repeatable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Repeatable.html)), the wrapper annotation `@JoinColumns` is no longer required .

So, you can simply do this:

```java
// bi-directional many-to-one association to Provincia
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "codProvincia", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "codRegion", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Provincia provincia;
```

References:

[Java 8's new Type Annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-8s-new-type-annotations)

[Repeating Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html)