# Foreign key mapping to Embeddable class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using `Hibernate` to join Entity1 to Entity2 where Entity2 have a composite primary key.

`Entity2` contains 2 columns `id` and `type`

```
public class Entity2 {
  @EmbeddedId
  private Entity2PK id;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class Entity2PK implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "type")
  private String type;
}
```

`Entity1` contains 2 columns `id` and `entity_2_id` (foreign key ref to `Entity2`)

```
public class Entity1 {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="entity_2_id")
  private Entity2 entity2;
}
```

All the calls are failing because of this. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Error Message:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering Entity2 from Entity1 has the wrong number of column. should be 4
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:646)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1814)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1758)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1646)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
```

Comment: Why are the calls failing? Can you post some error messages? Also is your Entity2PK annotated with @Embeddable?

Comment: Updated with error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have the same problem as this user: [AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering has the wrong number of column. should be 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215607/annotationexception-a-foreign-key-refering-has-the-wrong-number-of-column-shou)

Entity1 can not store the relationship in one single column, because Entity2 has an id with 2 columns. You can solve this by using `JoinColumns` instead of `JoinColumn`.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity2_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity2_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
private Entity2 entity2;
```

Comment: should `Entity1` have 2 columns for referencing foreign key. ? currently I am having only `entity_2_id` only.

Comment: You should have 2 columns. I updated my answer to make it more clear.